# excluding from Uber (fat) jar in sbt for Play! in Scala

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, unmanaged, uberjar

I have a project for which I have to include a fat-jar for some proprietary hardware - don't ask, I know its best for the jar to be on Central or some other repo, but it is not. :( I have to put it in the lib directory so sbt would treat it as an unmanaged dependency.

but the jar includes slf4j, an old version of it, and when Play! runs it throws an error complaining that a static function is missing (which was added in the newer versions of slf4j.

Here is what I have tried.

- I have tried to add the libraryDependency using force(). No dice.
- I have tried a couple of excludeAll samples I found here. No dice.
- out of sheer desperation, I unzipped the jar, removed slf4j, and created jar again. It Works!, but seriously this is not my first choice for maintaining the project.

Does anyone know of a way to exclude something inside an Uber jar that is an unmanaged dependency in an sbt-based scala or play project?

Answer (score 0):

You could [shade](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading) your managed slf4j library and make it seem as there is no dependency clash. To do this you can use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) shading ability.

For example, if you're using `slf4j-api`, it would look like this:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly ++= Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("org.slf4j.slf4j-api.**" -> "my_slf4j.@1")
    .inLibrary("org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.21")
    .inProject
)
```

This will cause anything using this specific version of slf4j to alter it's package name with a `my_slf4j` prefix instead of `org.slf4j`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but as I mentioned I need the managed version (which can also be excluded in the dependency any way) because it is the newer one. I need to somehow exclude the version in the unmanaged library.

Comment: The managed version is compiled with the uber jar, isn't it? If it is, the shading feature will shade the internal library used inside the jar, which I think is wjat you want